# sql server 2008 checksum algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sql-server-2008, checksum

i tried hard but i could not find what algorithm  is used in the checksum calculation for page validation in sql server 2008.how do they compute those four bytes in header . what is the  CHECKSUM algorithm used in sql server 2008 for page validation ?

Comment: i am also not sure whether they take whole 8192 bytes of page or they leave header and calculate checksum of non header part.tried both option on 010 editor to calculate checksum no checksum algorithm (implemented by 010 editor )matched those four bytes in header.

Comment: i managed to find that header is also included in checksum....